# Accessing a resource in routes.rb by using attributes other than Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

I have the following in my routes.rb

```
map.resources :novels do |novel|
  novel.resources :chapters
end
```

With the above defined route, I can access the chapters by using `xxxxx.com/novels/:id/chapters/:id`.
But this is not what I want, the Chapter model has another field called number (which corresponds to chapter number). I want to access each chapter through an URL which is something like 
`xxxx.com/novels/:novel_id/chapters/:chapter_number`. How can I accomplish this without explicitly defining a named route?

Right now I'm doing this by using the following named route defined ABOVE map.resources :novels

```
map.chapter_no 'novels/:novel_id/chapters/:chapter_no', :controller => 'chapters', :action => 'show'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:id` can be almost anything you want. So, leave the routing config untouched and change your action from

```
class ChaptersControllers
  def show
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

to (assuming the field you want to search for is called `:chapter_no`)

```
class ChaptersControllers
  def show
    @chapter = Chapter.find_by_chapter_no!(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Also note:

1. I'm using the bang! finder version (`find_by_chapter_no!` instead of `find_by_chapter_no`) to simulate the default `find` behavior
2. The field you are searching should have a database index for better performances

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, and I have one grudge with this method: show_chapter_url(chapter) doesn't work anymore. Is there a way around that, you think? Or should I just man up and use show_chapter_url(chapter.chapter_no) (or actually the equivalent in my own app)?